# How to fix error that gitlab CI returns after running karma tests?

Tags: karma-runner, gitlab-ci

I'm running karma tests on gitlab CI using this config:

```
test:
image: markadams/chromium-xvfb-js
stage: test
script:
- echo "Testing"
- apt-get install git -y
- cd ClientApp
- apt-get install libfontconfig -y
- npm install
- ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test --browsers=ChromeHeadless --watch=false
```

The job returned the following result:

```
TOTAL: 48 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 48 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 48 SUCCESS
19 12 2018 17:20:14.754:ERROR [karma]: { Error: spawn ps ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:232:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn ps',
  path: 'ps',
  spawnargs: [ '-o', 'pid', '--no-headers', '--ppid', 985 ] }
Job succeeded
```

Despite of that job succeeded, before that I had an error. How can I to get rid of it?

Comment: How did you fix this issue?

Comment: I didn't fix it. I'm going to build my app on azure instead of gitlab @atluriajith

Answer (score -2):

This issue is because of one of your test case is failing.

Comment: why is it failing if 48 from 48 were completed successfully?